# Image keeps rotating android studio

Tags: android, image

The picture keeps auto-rotating when I select an image from the gallery and the camera. I have tried the code below and I keep getting the same result. I am new to android studio so I cant find a way to correct the orientation of the image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap selectedImages = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            holdpic = getBytes(getResizedBitmaps(selectedImages, 350));
            patientPic.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmaps(selectedImages, 350));
            patientPic.setBackgroundResource(0);
            patientPic.setMaxHeight(350);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        holdpic = getBytes(getResizedBitmaps(image, 350));
        patientPic.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmaps(image, 350));
        patientPic.setMaxHeight(350);
        patientPic.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }


} 
  public Bitmap getResizedBitmaps(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
 }

    } else {

        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'the picture keeps auto rotating' ??? What is it that the user would see? It turns and it turns? It is unclear which result you get.

Comment: When I select pictures from a gallery or camera, it turns sideways when I view it on the Image view

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with with sideways.

Comment: It always turns 180°. It's supposed to be 90°, the orientation keeps messing up.

Comment: Turning or rotating? And it should be 0 degrees i think. Why 90? You explain nothing.

Comment: The orientation if the obtained camera bitmap is not correctable. But that of picked from gallery is. And you have been told what to use: ExifInteface.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before and tried to fix it with `Exifinterface`, but won't be worked, then I found a workaround, I used [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

```
Glide.with(ivImage)
     .load("file:${data[position].path}")
     .into(ivImage)
```

Comment: What does not work? You are difficult to help if you dont tell what you tried.